# Apache 2.4 MPM worker: Thread Init?

Tags: c, linux, apache, pthreads

I am writing an Apache 2.4 Module, and am using MPM worker.

Is there a hook I can use that gets called when a new thread is created, from the context of that thread?  I need to do some per-thread initialization.

(More generally, is there a comprehensive list of hooks documented somewhere?)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer in 'no', there is no such hook for thread initialization with the worker MPM. Apache designers recommend modules to be 'MPM agnostic as much as possible'. The key concept is that modules must fit the input filters - content generation - output filters architecture independently from the MPM that is actually managing the workload.

Of course there are cases where you need to know in which environment you're working tough

We are working on a similar problem. Threads are fired when requests come in, they run the hook defined in ap_hook_handler and, for what I understand,  that's the time when your thread must gain access or allocate the resources it will need in order to serve the requests.

I've been told mod_rivet has an interesting solution creating its own thread pool and letting them exchange data with the Apache threads running the request handler.

Comment: Yeah I read the worker MPM code, it just launches its thread pool after child_init with pthreads api.  The solution I use is to have a static thread_local object within a function: `X& f() { thread_local x; return x;`, and in the constructor run my thread_init function.  This works, but unfortunately you pay the thread_init time on first request to that worker thread (rather than immediately on thread starting up).